# Validating custom datetime with XML Schema

Tags: xml, datetime, xsd

Is it possible to validate a custom datetime format with XML Schema? I want to validate element that contains a datetime that matches `%Y%m%d%H%M%S` in `strftime` format.

For example ISO 8601 datetime `2015-02-21T14:36:06` would be `20150221143606`.

Answer (score 2):

Use XSD 1.1 and write an assertion that tests whether the data in your element can be used to construct a legal xsd:dateTime value; sub-string extraction functions and the dateTime constructor function will be your friends.

Answer (score 0):

Saxon has an extension facet saxon:preprocess that allows you (by means of an XPath expression) to convert your value before it is validated; this allows you to declare the type as xs:dateTime but in effect to define your own lexical representation of the values. Sadly this is non-standard, so it may not help you much.